# Receiving parse error after first line of code in lsolve command given in numerical analysis text

Tags: matlab, octave

The following code was given in the text of my numerical methods textbook, I copied it into Octave and get a parse error after "n = length(b);", and when  I tried to make n an input parameter, just to see if this would resolve the issue, the parse error is just shifted to the next line of code. This makes me feel as if the error is actually somewhere else in the code? Would appreciate any insight. Thanks!

```
function y = lsolve(L, b)
n = length(b);     
for i = 1: n,    
    y(i) = b(i);         
        for j = 1: i - 1,
        y(i) = y(i) - L(i, j) * y(j);
    end;
end;
```

Comment: It works for me (for `L` of size `r`x`c` and `b` of size `r`x`1`). How did you copy it into Octave? You should save it as a file to be able to use it as a function

Comment: I saved it as an m-file, and even restarted the program, but it still gives me the same parse error, but thank you for your help, I guess it might be an issue with my computer?

Comment: It's hard to tell. What character encoding does your editor use, or what editor are you using?

Comment: I confirm that this works for me too as is, after saving it in `lsolve.m` file and calling `lsolve([1 1; 0 1], [1; 1])`. Octave version: 5.1.0